# Automatic adding current time in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have table with a column of datatype `time(4)`.

When I'm inserting values into the table I need to auto insert just the current time with milliseconds (without date) into that column. I have tried with time stamp, date time... but without any success.

Comment: If you really don't want the date then use a date datatype. And just insert getdate(). It will implicitly convert getdate to a date datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange: or better yet - use `SYSDATETIME()` since that adapts more easily to whatever data type (`DATE`, `DATETIME2(n)` etc.) you might want and it has **more accuracy** - `GETDATE()` only returns the "somewhat deprecated" `DATETIME` (which has its share of issues with accuracy and such)

Comment: I agree with using SYSDATETIME but I don't know about datetime being "somewhat deprecated". :) It has some rounding issues but I have never needed millisecond accuracy with anything I have ever worked on. I can see in some situations where this level of accuracy would be important though.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the current time in SQL Server 2012, just use the `CAST` operator to achieve this:

```
SELECT  
   CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS TIME(4))
```

This will get the current date & time, and cast this to just the time, as you need it.

To achieve automatic entry of time values when a new row is added, you can use the above expression in a [default constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191289.aspx). For example:

```
DECLARE @T AS table
(
    SomeValue integer NOT NULL,
    TheTime time(4) NOT NULL 
        DEFAULT CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS time(4))
);

INSERT @T (SomeValue)
VALUES (1);

SELECT
    SomeValue,
    TheTime
FROM @T;
```

Comment: Not sure why somebody would downvote this unless they truly don't understand what is going on there. This is the way to do this.

Comment: @SeanLange: yeah, there are sometimes pretty strange folks hanging around on SO .... gotten used to that myself ....

Comment: And if you are inserting the value into a `time(4)` column, you don't even have to cast the result explicitly. (I probably wouldn't, in case the column's type might change some time later.)

Comment: @User4861279: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, this is what you may be looking for:

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today',
       CONVERT(TIME(4),GETDATE()) 'time_only'
```

You could use the above conversion in your insert statement as following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (
     column1
    ,column2
    ,record_insert_time
    )
VALUES (
     value1
    ,value2
    ,CONVERT(TIME(4), GETDATE())
    );
```

Comment: I just updated my answer since I just saw the question was updated. Don't know why would someone downvote. Clearly it says "As far as I understand".

Comment: The `CONVERT` using a style only works if you convert **to a `varchar`** - if you convert to a `TIME(4)`, you just convert to a `TIME(4)` which internally is a **binary format** (no string representation) - therefore this style 114 in the `CONVERT` is pointless in this particular situation